# Create and use an event so as to execute a block of code whenever a boolean in loop evaluates to true

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I want to know if there is a simple way to fire the below block of code by declaring and using an event. I want the below block of code to execute ONLY ONCE and IMMEDIATELY, whenever and each time during a cycle of my loop, a boolean called FireBlockofCode evaluates to true.

I understand I may have to use a delegate but I am not quite sure how.

A big thanks to all you wonderful gurus!

```
{
Console.WriteLine("starting a process");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
z = z * log(x);
Crystallize(y);

//Crystallize() is a time-consuming method
}
```

Comment: Here are some remarks: (1) Why a delegate? And what loop? (2) Have you been thinking about a Timer (with a very short interval as you said IMMEDIATELY) - in the timer tick event you test the boolean and when true, you reset it to false at the end (3) You'll need a * between the z and the log (4) If the Crysallize method is time consuming, have a background worker do it else it will freeze your app.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful thoughts and reply. 1 - I assume delegate is needed for implementing an event. The details of the loop are not important, except that the loop always needs to happen and the loop cannot be interrupted, slowed, or impeded by the Crystallize method; the loop basically behaves as a notifier, the source of notifications for the event, so to speak 2 - Timer would be good to compare against. 3 - Yes thanks. 4 - I assume that by implementing an event, the Crystallize's time-consumption will not interrupt the loop as compared with having the code block within the loop

Comment: (1) For events, you can set them with the GUI or programmatically, which event should trigger your method? (2) If no event, the timer should check regularily your boolean... Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Maybe timer is the way to go. I am not sure how efficient an event would be computationally, and I am not sure how to implement the event, programmatically or in Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe you already know this: when you click on an object, you have the properties displayed at right. If you click on the orange flash, you'll see all the event-related methods and if you double-clic on one of them, VS will create for you the corresponding method with the good parameters.

Comment: This is going to show my ignorance, so please forgive me. I am already in way over my head-->I don't think I have objects in my code (it is a simple console app with a few methods here and there and variables. Should I implement objects? Can this be done easily with VS GUI? I have Community Edition. Sorry.  "There are no stupid questions, just stupid people" haha

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you were with a windows form project, not console. Please tell more about your purpose, there's so much to be done with this tool (I use VS community too).